# Query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem with my query in MS Access 2000. I need to select by the current date in database. I put either function `date()` or `now` and it doesn't work.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT     TOP 100 PERCENT dbo.КАРНЕТ.НомКарнета, dbo.ФИРМА.НаимПредпр
 FROM         dbo.ФИРМА INNER JOIN
                  dbo.КАРНЕТ ON dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр = dbo.КАРНЕТ.КодПредпр
  WHERE     (dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтСдачи = CONVERT(DATE, 'DATE()', 102))
  GROUP BY dbo.КАРНЕТ.НомКарнета, dbo.ФИРМА.НаимПредпр;
```

Comment: What mean it doesn't work? You got empty result, or you got error message?

Comment: what is `dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтСдачи` format in `YYYYMMDD HHMMSS`

Comment: here is written the date when it was inserted like 31.01.2013

Comment: Try style 104 instead 102

Comment: You have tagged your question with `tsql`. You may be under the impression that Access supports Transact-SQL. It does not. It only supports JET/ACE's own, bastardised dialect of SQL. Don't bother using `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Date()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/date.php) without the single quotes:

```
WHERE dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтСдачи = Date()
```

The `Date()` function will return the current system date.

If your `dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтСдачи` has time included in it, then you might need to format that and you can also format the `Date()` value the same:

```
WHERE Format(dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтСдачи, "yyyy.mm.dd") = Format(Date(), "yyyy.mm.dd")
```

*Note: I just tested the above line in MS Access 2003 and it returned records. The code should be the same for MS Access 2000.*

Comment: Your second where clause is definitely best removing the time for both, just in case! +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATE(),'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Result in MS Access:

```
01.02.2013
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Try using `now()` or `today()` or `date()` **without the quotes**.
2. You may have no data for that day.
3. Also convert your field to a date format without the time, `convert(...)` or `format()` before you compare it to the `date()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can format dates any number of ways.

Format (#17/04/2004#, "Short Date")
Result: '17/04/2004'

Format (#17/04/2004#, "Long Date")
Result: 'April 17, 2004'

Format (#17/04/2004#, "yyyy/mm/dd")
Result: '2004/04/17'

```
Sub Createdate()
myDate = Format(Date, "Short Date")
End Sub
```

?myDate
12/29/2016